# Array of Data tables, check to determine if all have the same number of rows

Tags: c#

Using C# I have declared an array of datatables.  I now need a way of looking through each data table in the array and return true if the number of rows in each of the datatables are the same, or false if not

The length of the array can vary

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Linq` and do this.

```
// tables = new List<DataTable>(); 
if(tables.Select(x=>x.Rows.Count).Distinct().Count() ==1)
{
    ..      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the array with a loop. Here is an example pseudo code:

```
var value = DataTables.First().RowCount();
foreach(DataTable in DataTables){
    if(DataTable.RowCount() != value){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Count = ArrayDataTable.First().Rows.Count;
bool IsAllHasNotSameRowsCount = (from t in ArrayDataTable where t.Rows.Count != Count select t).Any();
```